# Grepping a variable

Tags: shell, python, ps, init-script

I've written a simple init script to start and stop a Python script as a service. I have to be explicit about the version of Python I'm running, because this is on a CentOS 5 box with Python 2.4 & 2.6 installed (both via yum).

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 123456 90 10

workdir=/usr/local/bin/Foo

start() {
    cd $workdir
    /usr/bin/python26 $workdir/Bar.py &
    echo "FooBar started."
}

stop() {
    pid=`ps -ef | grep '[p]ython26 /usr/local/bin/Foo/Bar.py' | awk '{ print $2 }'`
    echo $pid
    kill $pid
    sleep 2
    echo "FooBar stopped."
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/foobar {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

So:

1) I want to be "smarter" about the filename and directory name management, and set some variables up to so that anything repeated later in the script (like workdir). My main problem is the grep statement, and I haven't figured out how to deal with the variables inside the grep. I'd love any suggestions of a more efficient way to do this.

2) I want to add "status" support to this init script and have it check to see if the Bar.py is running.

Comment: Could you clarify what your grep is supposed to be doing? Why are you greping for all that if all you need is the PID of `Bar.py`? Why not use `pgrep`? Why is the python version relevant?

Comment: Great question - and the answer is because I never knew about pgrep! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something but I don't understand why you are fiddling with `grep` in the first place. That's what `pgrep` is for:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 123456 90 10

workdir=/usr/local/bin/Foo

start() {
    cd $workdir
    /usr/bin/python26 $workdir/Bar.py &
    echo "FooBar started."
}

stop() {
    pid=`pgrep -f '/Bar.py$'`
    echo $pid
    kill $pid
    sleep 2
    echo "FooBar stopped."
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/foobar {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

The `pgrep` command is designed to return the PIDs of processes whose name matches the pattern given. Since this is a python script, the actual process is something like:

```
python /usr/local/bin/Bar.py
```

Where the process name is `python`. So, we need to use pgrep's `-f` flag to match the entire name:

```
   -f, --full
          The pattern is normally only matched against the  process  name.
          When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

To ensure that this does not match things like `fooBar.py`, the pattern is `/Bar.py$` so that it matches only the portion after the last `/` and at the end of the string (`$`).

For future reference, you should never use `ps | grep` to get a PID. That will always return at least two lines, one for the running process and one for the grep you just launched:

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'Bar.py'
terdon   27209  2006 19 17:05 pts/9    00:00:00 python /usr/local/bin/Bar.py
terdon   27254  1377  0 17:05 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color Bar.py
```

Comment: Awesomeness. Didn't know pgrep, so thank you - this works great!